# Dynamically inserted header and footer don't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-toolbars

Hello guys I have one question...

I use JQM 1.4 ... and it sometimes happens that when i click a button an get reddirected (to a new HTML5 file)... on the new page  the header and footer are without style... it doesn't happen always but I cant have a page like this...

For the footer and header I use external HTML files (header.html and footer.html) and i call them with

```
$('#pageprostoriheader').load('header.html').trigger("create");
$('#pageprostorifooter').load('footer.html').trigger("create");
```

As I said it doesn't happen very often but when it does is ugly ...

I have a multiPage template and i think maybe this is caused because the header and footer don't get loaded quick enough ....  so its possible to make like a loader that waits till is everything ready till it shows the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, `.trigger("create")` is deprecated and will be removed on 1.5. Moreover, to create header/footer you should have used `.trigger("pagecreate")`, however, it is also deprecated and will be removed.

The replacement of the aforementioned functions is `.enhanceWthin()` to be called on parent element. This issue has several solutuins

1. Enhance *toolbars* after successful `.load()`, using `.toolbar()`.

   ```
   $('#pageprostoriheader').load('header.html', function () {
     $(this).toolbar();
   });

   $('#pageprostorifooter').load('footer.html', function () {
     $(this).toolbar();
   });
   ```
2. Enhance *toolbars* after successful `.load()`, using `.enhanceWithin()` on *active page*.

   ```
   $('#pageprostoriheader').load('header.html', function () {
     $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
   });

   $('#pageprostorifooter').load('footer.html', function () {
     $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
   });
   ```
3. If you're using the same *toolbars* on all pages, I recommend using *External toolbars*.

   Add HTML markup of header and footer in `<body>` not inside *page* div, and then add the below code in *head* after jQuery Mobile.js.

   ```
   $(function () {
      $("[data-role=header], [data-role=footer]").toolbar();
   });
   ```

Comment: this option works for me ... thanks ... Enhance toolbars after successful .load(), using .enhanceWithin() on active page.