# What is the most efficient way to keep header/footer inside JQM multi-pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking for an efficient solution to maintain the same header and footer inside a jQuery Mobile Multipage setup. The page provides a "select category" functionality with about 300 categories across 50 pages.

e.g.

```
<div data-role="page" id="select_maincat">  
   <div data-role="header" class="fixedHeader">...</div>
   <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Wählen Sie eine Kategorie aus:</h1> 
        <ul data-role="listview">
           <li><a href="#dienstleistungen">Dienstleistungen</a></li>
        </ul>     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">...</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="dienstleistungen">  
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#betreuung-pflege">Betreuung & Pflege</a></li>
        </ul>     
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Adding the same footer/header to each page inside the MP is easy with PHP but will increase the load time significantly as it is quite a bit of code and this does not look very efficient to me. I am looking for an elegant solution in order to keep load times as small as possible.

There is a similar posting I have found: [How to keep same header/footer across pages in jQueryMobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712577/how-to-keep-same-header-footer-across-pages-in-jquerymobile) However this does not seem to be exactly the same question.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Use external toolbars. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21305056/1771795

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This somehow works, but the navigation disapears once you click on the screen: https://jsfiddle.net/8dq33596/7/

Comment: add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to both header and footer.

Comment: Thank's. That works. Something still seems wrong as I have to hit reload to see the header/footer upon page load.

Comment: Also the header inside the fiddle is not aligned anymore to the left but has a margin. Once you click on the list items the red header fills the entire page for a second.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8dq33596/21/

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid, please read more about [external toolbars](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-external/).

Comment: Thank you, I did fix it and did read more about the topic. However, somehow there still is an error in layout: https://jsfiddle.net/x_merlin_x/esb6j7wa/5/ The first navi element is not possitioined OK (in comparison to the 2nd listview)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/esb6j7wa/7/